# How to login to a website with no username when using lynx?

Tags: linux, router, http, authentication, lynx

I'm trying to login to a Linksys router web interface using lynx.  From what I understand, if I use the command

`lynx -auth=username:password http://192.168.1.1/`

I can login with basic http authentication.  However the router's default password contains no username, and a password of `admin`.  So how can I login considering the username is blank?

Comment: what happens if you just go to http://192.168.1.1 without providing a username?   Shouldn't it prompt you for credentials if you do it that way?   Are you trying to script or automate something?

Comment: It does prompt me for a username, but then it asks me if I want to login without a username and password; if I say `Y` I get the `not authorized page` if I answer `N` I try to press enter to avoid the username, but it just exits then instead of letting me enter the password.

Comment: What if you try `username:password@192.168.1.1/` although not sure how to pass a `null` (e.g. empty) username. Try and see if `lynx http://"":password@192.168.1.1/` works.